# How to detect if Internet Explorer video exits fullscreen mode?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, video, fullscreen

On my page I have a video which enters fullscreen mode the following way:

```
$('.fullscreen-btn').click(function () {
            if (movie[0].requestFullscreen) {                
              movie[0].requestFullscreen();
            } else if (movie[0].mozRequestFullScreen) {                
                movie[0].mozRequestFullScreen();              
            } else if (movie[0].webkitRequestFullscreen) {                
                movie[0].webkitRequestFullscreen();
            } else if(movie[0].webkitEnterFullscreen){ //ipad fix
                movie[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
            } else if (movie[0].msRequestFullscreen){ //IE fix
                movie[0].msRequestFullscreen();
            }
            //followed by some code for smallscreen button, positioning customized play and pause button etc. 
});
```

When I leave fullscreen mode I have the following code to detect it:

```
$('.smallscreen-btn').click(function () {
                if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                    document.exitFullscreen();
                }
                else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen();                   
                }
                else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                }
                if(movie[0].webkitExitFullscreen){ //ipad specific
                ...
                }
});
```

But I don't know what condition works for IE:
I tried `if(document.msExitFullScreen){...}`, `if(movie[0].msExitFullScreen){...}`

So I know how to detect entering fullscreen mode but not cancelling it. Anyone knows what could work?

Comment: maybe MSFullscreenChange as it says from the docs? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265028(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh yeah! Thank you! msExitFullScreen didn't work but the MS fullscreen change event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn312066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx did the job :)

Comment: sometimes google helps ;)

Comment: I tried but it seems I have no talent for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This JavaScript (vanilla) solution should be widely supported. This is a small api that will enable you to detect when client enters the fullscreen mode as well as when exiting. It is event-driven therefore very simple to use, and will work on all DOM2 customEvent supported browsers.
Browsers (old enough) that don't support `outerHeight : innerHeight` properties will fail.

```
onresize = function() {
        var state = 1 >= outerHeight - innerHeight ? "fullscreen" : "windowed";
            if( window.state == state ) return;
        window.state = state;
        var event = document.createEvent("Event");
            event.initEvent(state, true, true);
            window.dispatchEvent( event );
    };

    addEventListener('windowed', function(e){ alert(e.type) }, false );
    addEventListener('fullscreen', function(e){ alert(e.type) }, false );
```

*! never tested on smartphones though, please check and provide relevant feedback.